# Application Load Balancer Behaving Badly

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-status-code-400, elastic-load-balancer

So last week we noticed a spike in our ELB 400 errors, and when we dove into the logs we discovered something strange that we can't figure out.

A request url formatted like below is hitting the Application Load Balancer 40 times a second consistently.

```
https://autodeploy-xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443
```

The IPs seem to come from Amazon themselves, which make sense since the above url is not how we send traffic to our ELB. and the ports the are coming over are not ports enabled on the ELB hence the 400 errors, but this is significantly increasing our costs as our Load Balancer Units have doubled because of it, and we haven't added any service that should act this way.

```
Sample IP: 34.207.214.113:21556
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You don't have port 443 enabled on your ALB? Is your load balancer named `autodeploy` by chance? That just looks like the standard DNS name that would be assigned to your ALB. That IP address is from within the AWS us-east-1 region. I doubt anybody here is going to be able to help you much, you should open a support ticket with AWS.

Comment: that port is open, looks like we will have to open a ticket most likely. that is the name of the load balancer.

Comment: So it's just something hitting the default SSL port on your load balancer via the load balancer's DNS name. Whatever is doing it is coming from within AWS. I'd check to make sure none of your EC2 instances have `34.207.214.113` as the public IP address.

Comment: They don't. and each one of these requests in the log comes from a similar IP format but different ending digits like 34.229.239.201 or 34.227.84.154.34 and so on.

Comment: Do you have Route53 Health Monitors defined? Or any records in Route53 pointing to the ALB with "Evaluate Target Health" enabled? (I'm just guessing at this point what AWS service may be creating that traffic)

Comment: No all Route53 Health Checks are disabled.